# Ubuntu not connect internet

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet

My ubuntu server 20.04 one day suddenly lost its network and when ping google, the program said:

Temporary failure in name resolution

And sometimes spam out 5-6 lines like that:

```
[10996.368815] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 ( loop: 100, delay: 100 )    
[10996.390953] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 ( loop: 100, delay: 100 )    
[10996.415280] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 ( loop: 100, delay: 100 )    
[10996.438666] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: rtl_eriar_cond == 1 ( loop: 100, delay: 100 )
```

File /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53    
options edns0 trust-ad    
search .
```

File /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

```
network:
   ethernets:
     addresses:
     - 192.168.1.3/24
     routes:
     - to: default
       via: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
     - 192.168.1.1
version: 2
```

My ifconfig:

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500    
inet 192.168.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255    
inet6 2001:ee0:41c1:74c7:d217:c2ff:fe1c:49a1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x0<global>    
inet6 fe80::d217:c2ff:fe1c:49a1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>    
RX packets 120 bytes 22176 (22.1 KB)    
RX errors 0 dropped 43 bytes 3632 (3.6 KB)
```